# Rails - nested content_tag (:ul -> :li -> :div) render the div html tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I'm trying to nest content tags into a custom helper, to create something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Microposts
    <div>O</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried this helper:

```
def user_info(user)
   user_microposts = content_tag(:li,  ("Microposts" + " " + content_tag(:div, user.microposts.count.to_s)))
  content_tag(:ul, user_microposts)
end
```

but it renders the div html tags in the view:

```
Microposts
<div>0</div>
```

I would be pleased to know how to manage this!
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark the string as HTML-safe, like this:

```
... "Microposts ".html_safe + content_tag(...
```